# how to use multiple app.get in node js to render different webpages on different calls

Tags: node.js

i have been trying to use noje.js to render webpages by using app.get syntax

but it is only working for "/" not for anyother

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home",{startingContent:homeStartingContent})
});

app.get("/about ", function(req, res) {
  res.render("about",{ aboutContent:aboutContent})
});

app.get("/contact ", function(req, res) {
  res.render("contact",{ aboutContact:contactContent})
});
```

the error that i keep getting is --Cannot GET /about

i tried using only a single app.get but it only works for "/"

Comment: try removing the spaces after the route
`"/about "` should be `"/about"`